# Webpage loop through images in a directory

Tags: php, javascript, html, cron

I would like to create a webpage that loops through all the images in a directory and displays and displays the image in an iframe with 10 second intervals. It also polls the directory constantly for new images. I don't have very much Javascript/PHP experience so just need an idea of where to start. Sorry for the newby question.

Comment: Have you tried searching on google? https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+photo+gallery Galleria looks good - http://galleria.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

These examples are programmed in javascript. This should be enough to get you started. Look at the pages source code.

Comment: No my friend, it really doesn't - http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml

Comment: Perfect this did the trick.